# Getting TCP connection count for a process

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

Basically, I want to pull the active TCP connections for a process (by name) without pulling all tcp info and parsing the output.

Defining my process as follows:

```
Process[] whatever = Process.GetProcessByName("whatever.exe");
```

I want a count of TCP connections for a given process which I specify.

Comment: To clarify: you want the TCP connection *count* for a particular process? If so, please edit your question accordingly (and not with "Edit: blah blah blah"; edit the whole thing).

Comment: [GetExtendedTcpTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365928(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: :) Will do, thank you.